# How to manage DNS on Netlify when domain is registered with Route53

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, netlify

so I am looking for a way to point records of existing domain registered on Route53 but managed by Netlify DNS.

I want to point the records to a different netlify url if possible but it will not allow me to edit the domain. Maybe what i am trying to do is not possible but here are some images to give an idea

this is netlify

[image]

this is route 53

[image]

I want to once again point my url.com to a different url then what is currently being used.

Answer (score 1):

Note:  I work for Netlify and have solved this problem for other customers in the past.

You cannot have DNS managed by route53 and ALSO set NS records pointing elsewhere for your main domain, or at least, I've seen that fail several times for folks trying to use Netlify's DNS hosting.  You need to instead set the nameservers at your registrar to point to Netlify's nameservers.  Netlify only has the capability to host DNS for domains (not subdomains), so if you are attempting to delegate a subdomain to Netlify, that will also fail.

You'll be able to tell you've done this right when the SOA record for your domain points to Netlify's nameservers.  Below is an example query that demonstrates that NS1 is the delegated-to authority:

```
$ dig -t SOA fools.website
[...]
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fools.website.         IN  SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
fools.website.      3600    IN  SOA dns1.p03.nsone.net. hostmaster.nsone.net. 1543948999 43200 7200 1209600 3600
[...]
```

Comment: when I type in my domain with the command you gave it appears to be pointing correctly to netlify `traxit.io.              3600    IN      SOA     dns1.p03.nsone.net. hostmaster.nsone.net. 1545709866 43200 7200 1209600 3600` however I guess my question is, should this same soa record be in route53 as well?

Comment: Yup, I can see you've now correctly changed your nameservers at your registrar, so things should work right with Netlify (versus when I checked 2 days ago you had nameservers set to AWS @ your registrar).  If they aren't, please ping the helpdesk so we can help you get things sorted out there.